# Is a process killed if the thread that started it is aborted?

Tags: c#, .net

If I create a thread that starts a process and later abort that thread, does the process stop executing as a result of the thread being aborted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not clear as to what the question is asking.  When you start a process by launching an .exe file, there will be the primary thread for the process; if this thread aborts for whatever reason then the process will also halt.
If you are talking about a thread launching another process (via the Process class Start method for example) then the exiting of the thread that launched the process will not stop the process.

Answer (score 2):

No, since the thread will be in a totally different process (you just started a new process), there is no link between them.

(also if you started another thread, the other thread would not be killed).